# Remove-ADUser: -Server paramter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way we can know against which server this command is executing?

I have [read the documentation for the command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617206.aspx) but it says will use the default. But how can we be sure?

> The default value for the Server parameter is determined by one of the
>   following methods in the order that they are listed:
>
> - By using Server value from objects passed through the pipeline.
> - By using the server information associated with the Active Directory PowerShell provider drive, when running under that drive.
> - By using the domain of the computer running Powershell.

Comment: Maybe that `-WhatIf` parameter e.g. `Remove-ADUser -Identity OKadhim -WhatIf` could help?

Comment: This may not be an answer to your question, but maybe it can be helpful. Take a look at this link to change the 'default' connected DC, to a given DC: https://serverfault.com/questions/527545/how-to-set-a-default-domain-controller-for-all-powershell-ad-cmdlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `Remove-ADUser` (or computer, or object) - the default domain controller for the current domain will be used.

If you're deleting a user from your current domain - you can see whcih DC will be used by using the command `Get-ADDomainController -Writable -Discover`

If you're crossing domains or forests - you add the `-DomainName` switch to give you `Get-ADDomainController -Writable -Discover -DomainName "yourDomain.com"`

This will return an object which includes a "Name" Attribute.

This Cmdlet uses the same discovery method that PowerShell will use when connecting to AD to delete a user or othr object.